# SQL Query Date compare options

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare the current date with database datetime column. I tried the following three options, but no luck. Any idea?

**Option 1**

```
select something from tableA
where  cast(lastupdateddate as date)=cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

**Option 2**

```
select something from tableA
where  CONVERT(date, lastupdateddate)=CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

**Option 3**

```
select something from tableA
where  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), lastupdateddate,1)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),1)
```

Comment: mysql? i've found the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function to be pretty reliable......http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: timediff along with time_to_sec is what is generally use

Comment: @A.O., its SQL Server 2012

Comment: oops..I am out then.. :D

Comment: oh ok, well I think `DATEDIFF` is the server equivalent. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Why all the casts?  What data type is your lastupdatedate column?

Comment: The Cast and converts that you have mentioned should work. I just tested it. Are you sure you have data where the lastupdateddate date part is equal to today's date?

Comment: @Andrew, as I mentioned in the questions its datetime datatype.

Comment: What are the chances that what you are comparing it with in db is same as the time returned by GETDATE(), this comparison means you need to have a row inserted at the same time you are making the comparison.. is that what you want?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan, i need the records which matches to the current date. It doesn't have to be the same time, its same date.

Comment: as @TMNT2014 mentions what you have should work. I would select out the criteria to see what's going on e.g. `select cast(lastupdateddate as date) LastUpdateDate, cast(GETDATE() as date) today from tableA`

Comment: i am not sure but this works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b58e/2

Answer (score 0):

Right the first option should already work, provided the column has really `datetime` datatype, e.g.

```
create table tablea (
  id int,
  lastupdateddate datetime
);
```

and the query

```
select *
from tablea
where cast(lastupdateddate as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d14a/1)